# Need unique values using with Listagg function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one query in which I am using Listagg function and it is showing two same values and both values are same so i want to display only one value in the report

```
SELECT LISTAGG (OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP , ',') 
               WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP) 
  FROM ORDER_RELEASE ORR, 
       OB_ORDER_BASE OB , 
       SHIPMENT SH , 
       ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
 WHERE ORR.ORDER_BASE_GID = OB.ORDER_BASE_GID 
   AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
   AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID 
   AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070627'
```

Comment: SELECT LISTAGG (OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP , ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP)
  FROM ORDER_RELEASE ORR,
    OB_ORDER_BASE OB ,
    SHIPMENT SH ,
    ORDER_MOVEMENT OM
  WHERE ORR.ORDER_BASE_GID = OB.ORDER_BASE_GID
  AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID      = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
  AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
  AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID      = 'ULA/SAO.5000070627'

Comment: Don't add code in comments. [edit] your question

Comment: Put the query in your question.  Also fix the query to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hi I am new here and tried to edit the code but i could not do so. if you can help me to solve the query it would be very nice for me as it is very urgent for me

Answer (score 4):

Or you can replace the duplicate values by regular expression.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        LISTAGG (OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP),
        '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
        '\1'
    )
FROM
    ORDER_RELEASE ORR, 
    OB_ORDER_BASE OB , 
    SHIPMENT SH , 
    ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
WHERE 
    ORR.ORDER_BASE_GID = OB.ORDER_BASE_GID 
    AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
    AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID 
    AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070627'
```

Comment: Accurate solution! Thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no way to get rid of the duplicate row (often, people get duplicate values because they have failed to do the joins properly and have missed some condition), you can do a `distinct` as a first step in an inline view and then do the `listagg`

```
SELECT LISTAGG (a.SHIP_WITH_GROUP , ',') 
               WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY a.SHIP_WITH_GROUP) 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT OB.SHIP_WITH_GROUP
          FROM ORDER_RELEASE ORR, 
               OB_ORDER_BASE OB , 
               SHIPMENT SH , 
               ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
         WHERE ORR.ORDER_BASE_GID = OB.ORDER_BASE_GID 
           AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
           AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID 
           AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070627') a
```