# PL/SQL: How to get rid of duplicate values when using 2 listagg in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

Context:
This is an assignment where I have to recreate a basic version of Netflix's movie database using SQL developer. As part of that assignment, I have to create a view that lets me see the title, year of publication, duration, description, list of directors and list of actors of a movie.

SQL developer version: 20.4.0.379.2205-x64

PL/SQL version: 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

---

Tables:

NETFLIX_FILMS(film_id, titre, annee_sortie, duration, description)

NETFLIX_ACTEURS(acteur_id, surnom_acteur, prenom_acteur)

NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF(acteur_id, film_id)

NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS(directeur_id, surnom_directeur, prenom_directeur)

NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF(directeur_id, film_id)

---

To help explain the issue I'm having, I'll use the following movie example:

Titre: The book of Eli

Directeur(s): Albert Hughes, Allen Hughes

Acteur(s): Denzel Washington, Gary Oldman, Mila Kunis

Année sortie: 2010

Duration: 118

Description: Determined to protect a sacred text that promises to save humanity, Eli goes on a quest westward across the barren, post-apocalyptic county.

---

I have been trying to use listagg to get the list of directors as a single string and the list of actors as a single string. However, when I try to use both listaggs in the same select statement, it creates duplicates and I can't seem to figure out how to remove them.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
SELECT
    NETFLIX_FILMS.TITRE,
    NETFLIX_FILMS.ANNEE_SORTIE,
    NETFLIX_FILMS.DURATION,
    NETFLIX_FILMS.DESCRIPTION,
    LISTAGG(NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS.PRENOM_DIRECTEUR 
            || ' ' || NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS.SURNOM_DIRECTEUR || ', ') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_DIRECTEUR, SURNOM_DIRECTEUR) 
            AS NOM_DIRECTEUR,
    LISTAGG(NETFLIX_ACTEURS.PRENOM_ACTEUR 
            || ' ' || NETFLIX_ACTEURS.SURNOM_ACTEUR || ', ') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_ACTEUR, SURNOM_ACTEUR) 
            AS NOM_ACTEUR
FROM NETFLIX_FILMS
INNER JOIN NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF
    ON NETFLIX_FILMS.FILM_ID = NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF.FILM_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN NETFLIX_ACTEURS
    ON NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF.ACTEUR_ID = NETFLIX_ACTEURS.ACTEUR_ID
INNER JOIN NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF
    ON NETFLIX_FILMS.FILM_ID = NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF.FILM_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS
    ON NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF.DIRECTEUR_ID = NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS.DIRECTEUR_ID
GROUP BY NETFLIX_FILMS.TITRE, NETFLIX_FILMS.ANNEE_SORTIE, NETFLIX_FILMS.DURATION, NETFLIX_FILMS.DESCRIPTION;
```

This gives me the following:

Titre: The book of Eli

Directeur(s): Albert Hughes, Albert Hughes, Albert Hughes, Allen Hughes, Allen Hughes, Allen Hughes

Acteur(s): Denzel Washington, Denzel Washington, Gary Oldman, Gary Oldman, Mila Kunis, Mila Kunis

Année sortie: 2010

Duration: 118
Description: Determined to protect a sacred text that promises to save humanity, Eli goes on a quest westward across the barren, post-apocalyptic county.

---

The expected outcome is:

Titre: The book of Eli

Directeur(s): Albert Hughes, Allen Hughes

Acteur(s): Denzel Washington, Gary Oldman, Mila Kunis

Année sortie: 2010

Duration: 118

Description: Determined to protect a sacred text that promises to save humanity, Eli goes on a quest westward across the barren, post-apocalyptic county.

The directors are duplicated for each actor and the actors are duplicated for each director. This only happens when I use both listaggs in the same select statement. Listagg(distinct ...) isn't supported in this version of SQL and I can't seem to find another way to fix this.

Comment: SQL Developer is an IDE that is used to talk to database; it is **NOT** a database so giving us the SQL Developer version is not helpful. What you need is to provide the version of the Oracle database you are using.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.

The version is:
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have 3 actors and 2 directors and when you join all the tables together then you get 3x2 = 6 rows (as each actor is joined with each director) and then when you aggregate you get the names for all 6 rows which gives you duplicates. What you want to do is to aggregate the actors without joining the directors and aggregate the directors without joining the actors so that in both aggregations you do not generate duplicates and do not need to filter them out. You can do that in a couple of ways:

1. Use correlated sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT f.TITRE,
       f.ANNEE_SORTIE,
       f.DURATION,
       f.DESCRIPTION,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  PRENOM_ACTEUR || ' ' || SURNOM_ACTEUR,
                  ', '
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_ACTEUR, SURNOM_ACTEUR) 
         FROM   NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF r
                INNER JOIN NETFLIX_ACTEURS a
                ON r.ACTEUR_ID = a.ACTEUR_ID
         WHERE  f.FILM_ID = r.FILM_ID
       ) AS NOM_ACTEUR,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  d.PRENOM_DIRECTEUR || ' ' || d.SURNOM_DIRECTEUR,
                  ', '
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_DIRECTEUR, SURNOM_DIRECTEUR) 
         FROM   NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF r
                INNER JOIN NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS d
                ON e.DIRECTEUR_ID = d.DIRECTEUR_ID
         WHERE  f.FILM_ID = r.FILM_ID
       ) AS NOM_DIRECTEUR
FROM   NETFLIX_FILMS f;
```

2. Or aggregate and then join:

```sql
SELECT f.TITRE,
       f.ANNEE_SORTIE,
       f.DURATION,
       f.DESCRIPTION,
       a.NOM_ACTEUR,
       d.NOM_DIRECTEUR
FROM   NETFLIX_FILMS f
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT r.film_id,
                LISTAGG(
                  PRENOM_ACTEUR || ' ' || SURNOM_ACTEUR,
                  ', '
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_ACTEUR, SURNOM_ACTEUR) 
                  AS NOM_ACTEUR
         FROM   NETFLIX_ACTEURS_REF r
                INNER JOIN NETFLIX_ACTEURS a
                ON r.ACTEUR_ID = a.ACTEUR_ID
         GROUP BY r.film_id
       ) a
       ON (f.FILM_ID = a.FILM_ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT r.film_id,
                LISTAGG(
                  d.PRENOM_DIRECTEUR || ' ' || d.SURNOM_DIRECTEUR,
                  ', '
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_DIRECTEUR, SURNOM_DIRECTEUR) 
                  AS NOM_DIRECTEUR
         FROM   NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS_REF r
                INNER JOIN NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS d
                ON e.DIRECTEUR_ID = d.DIRECTEUR_ID
         GROUP BY r.film_id
       ) d
       ON f.FILM_ID = d.FILM_ID;
```

Comment: Using the correlated sub-queries worked wonders.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure which version Oracle you have and therefor not sure if you could use DISTINCT together with LISTAGG with your version (DISTINCT requires 19c and above). You can use the regex answer described here in order to remove the duplicates since this should work regardless of Oracle version:

[Need unique values using with Listagg function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292566/need-unique-values-using-with-listagg-function)

so in your case the following would apply:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(
LISTAGG(NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS.PRENOM_DIRECTEUR|| ' ' || NETFLIX_DIRECTEURS.SURNOM_DIRECTEUR || ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_DIRECTEUR, SURNOM_DIRECTEUR),
        '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
        '\1'
) AS NOM_DIRECTEUR,
REGEXP_REPLACE(
LISTAGG(NETFLIX_ACTEURS.PRENOM_ACTEUR|| ' ' || NETFLIX_ACTEURS.SURNOM_ACTEUR || ', ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRENOM_ACTEUR, SURNOM_ACTEUR),
        '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
        '\1'
) AS NOM_ACTEUR
```

I hope that helps and good luck in your assignment.